# Select Data every 5 minutes interval of specific Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data of every seconds of  800 different id which is almost 48232 rows. Sample data is pasted below.

```
 Id        DateTime              Value
 2999   14/11/2022 9:02:43        0.84
 2999   14/11/2022 9:03:14        0.79
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:14       67
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:24       69    
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:35       66    
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:36       66
 2999   14/11/2022 11:18:24       0.73
 2999   14/11/2022 11:57:36       0.65
 2999   14/11/2022 12:00:22       0.84
 2999   14/11/2022 18:03:12       0.62
 2999   14/11/2022 19:04:27       0.75
 2999   14/11/2022 19:04:54       0.67
 4511   14/11/2022 6:12:43        0.67
 4511   14/11/2022 6:29:42        0.98
 4511   14/11/2022 6:31:05        0.84
 4511   14/11/2022 6:31:10        0.88
 4511   14/11/2022 16:39:35       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:39:36       69   
 4511   14/11/2022 16:39:59       70
 4511   14/11/2022 16:40:00       70
 4511   14/11/2022 16:40:55       77
 4511   14/11/2022 16:40:56       78
 4511   14/11/2022 16:41:00       78    
 4511   14/11/2022 16:41:56       72
 4511   14/11/2022 16:41:58       72    
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:00       71
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:55       67
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:57       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:57       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:59       66    
 4511   14/11/2022 16:43:01       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:43:02       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:43:03       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:43:04       66
 4511   14/11/2022 17:03:15       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:03:31       68
 4511   14/11/2022 17:03:33       69
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:00       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:00       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:01       67     
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:01       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:01       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:14:07       66
```

need to select data after each 5 minutes of specific id. required data sample pasted below

```
Id        DateTime            Value
2999   14/11/2022 9:02:43       0.84
2999   14/11/2022 10:03:14      67
2999   14/11/2022 11:18:24      0.73
2999   14/11/2022 11:57:36      0.65
2999   14/11/2022 18:03:12      0.62
2999   14/11/2022 19:04:27      0.75
4511   14/11/2022 6:12:43       0.67
4511   14/11/2022 6:29:42       0.98
4511   14/11/2022 16:39:35      66
4511   14/11/2022 17:03:15      67
4511   14/11/2022 17:14:07      66
```

I am using below query to access specific result, need to improve the query performance query as it takes too much time to execute.

```
 WITH rcte AS (
 SELECT curr.*
 FROM [dbo].[Test] AS curr
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM [dbo].[Test]
  WHERE Id= curr.Id AND DateTime< curr.DateTime
 )
UNION ALL
 SELECT curr.*
 FROM rcte AS prev
 JOIN [dbo].[Test] AS curr ON prev.Id= curr.Id AND curr.DateTime>= DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, 
  prev.DateTime)
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM [dbo].[Test]
    WHERE Id= curr.Id AND DateTime < curr.DateTime AND DateTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, 
   prev.DateTime)
   )
   )
  SELECT *, case when rcte.Value > 0.6 and rcte.Value <=1.5 then 'Accel' 
   when rcte.Value >1.6 and rcte.Value<= 2.5 then 'Brk'
  else 'nthng' end as Vt
  FROM rcte
  ORDER BY 1;
```

execution file is attached for to achieve result
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VTqvLG9pxv7ecmEvuJk8n_-1nzxyopyF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Performance related questions require an execution plan (using Paste The Plan) and table and index definitions.

Comment: any issue in query @DaleK

Comment: This performance-related question lacks schema, indices and an execution plan. [How to include an SQL Server execution plan to a Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382341/how-to-include-an-sql-server-execution-plan-to-a-stack-overflow-question).

Comment: @enigma we can't tell without the missing information

Comment: @DaleK execution file is attached.